# Left Join two union select

Tags: mysql, database

I have problem with joining two select union result in mysql, can anyone help me?
this is my query

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT T1.*,T2.target FROM (
(SELECT skpd.kd_skpd AS kd_skpd,CONCAT_WS(' ','','','','','') as 
no_rekening, skpd.nm_skpd as nama from skpd WHERE skpd.kd_skpd='SD001'
UNION 
SELECT '' as kd,CONCAT_WS(' ',B.k_akun,'','','','') as no_rekening, 
B.nm_akun from m_akun_rek B
UNION
SELECT '' as kd,CONCAT_WS(' ',B.k_akun,B.k_kel,'','','') as no_rekening, 
B.nm_kel from m_kel_rek B, rekening_skpd A WHERE B.k_akun = A.k_akun AND 
B.k_kel=A.k_kel and A.kd_skpd='SD001'
UNION
SELECT '' as kd,CONCAT_WS(' ',B.k_akun,B.k_kel,B.k_jenis,'','') as 
no_rekening, B.nm_jenis from m_jenis_rek B, rekening_skpd A WHERE B.k_akun = 
A.k_akun AND B.k_kel=A.k_kel AND B.k_jenis = A.k_jenis and A.kd_skpd='SD001'
UNION
SELECT '' as kd,CONCAT_WS(' ',B.k_akun,B.k_kel,B.k_jenis,B.k_obyek,'') as 
no_rekening, B.nm_obyek from m_obyek_rek B, rekening_skpd A WHERE B.k_akun = 
A.k_akun AND B.k_kel=A.k_kel AND B.k_jenis = A.k_jenis AND 
B.k_obyek=A.k_obyek and A.kd_skpd='SD001'
UNION
SELECT '' as kd,CONCAT_WS(' 
',B.k_akun,B.k_kel,B.k_jenis,B.k_obyek,B.k_rekening) as no_rekening, 
B.nm_rekening from m_rekening B, rekening_skpd A WHERE B.k_akun = A.k_akun 
AND B.k_kel=A.k_kel AND B.k_jenis = A.k_jenis AND B.k_obyek=A.k_obyek AND 
B.k_rekening=A.k_rekening and A.kd_skpd='SD001'
) T1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT skpd.kd_skpd AS kd_skpd,CONCAT_WS(' ','','','','','') as 
no_rekening, skpd.nm_skpd as nama,'' as target from skpd WHERE 
skpd.kd_skpd='SD001'
UNION 
SELECT '' as kd,CONCAT_WS(' ',B.k_akun,'','','','') as no_rekening, 
B.nm_akun, SUM(A.nominal_target) as target from m_akun_rek B, target_tahunan 
A WHERE A.kd_skpd ='SD001' AND A.k_akun = B.k_akun AND A.tahun_target = 
'2017'
UNION
SELECT '' as kd,CONCAT_WS(' ',B.k_akun,B.k_kel,'','','') as no_rekening, 
B.nm_kel, SUM(C.nominal_target) as target from m_kel_rek B, rekening_skpd A, 
target_tahunan C WHERE B.k_akun = A.k_akun AND B.k_kel=A.k_kel and 
A.kd_skpd='SD001' AND C.k_akun = B.k_akun AND C.k_kel=A.k_kel and 
C.kd_skpd='SD001' AND C.tahun_target = '2017'
UNION
SELECT '' as kd,CONCAT_WS(' ',B.k_akun,B.k_kel,B.k_jenis,'','') as 
no_rekening, B.nm_jenis, SUM(C.nominal_target) as target from m_jenis_rek B, 
rekening_skpd A, target_tahunan C WHERE B.k_akun = A.k_akun AND 
B.k_kel=A.k_kel AND B.k_jenis = A.k_jenis and A.kd_skpd='SD001' AND C.k_akun 
= B.k_akun AND C.k_kel=B.k_kel AND C.k_jenis = B.k_jenis and 
C.kd_skpd='SD001' AND C.tahun_target = '2017'
UNION
SELECT '' as kd,CONCAT_WS(' ',B.k_akun,B.k_kel,B.k_jenis,B.k_obyek,'') as 
no_rekening, B.nm_obyek, SUM(C.nominal_target) as target from m_obyek_rek B, 
rekening_skpd A, target_tahunan C WHERE B.k_akun = A.k_akun AND 
B.k_kel=A.k_kel AND B.k_jenis = A.k_jenis AND B.k_obyek=A.k_obyek and 
A.kd_skpd='SD001' AND C.k_akun = B.k_akun AND C.k_kel=B.k_kel AND C.k_jenis 
= B.k_jenis AND C.k_obyek = B.k_obyek and C.kd_skpd='SD001' AND 
C.tahun_target = '2017'
UNION
SELECT '' as kd,CONCAT_WS(' 
',B.k_akun,B.k_kel,B.k_jenis,B.k_obyek,B.k_rekening) as 
no_rekening,B.nm_rekening, SUM(C.nominal_target) as target from m_rekening 
B,rekening_skpd A, target_tahunan C WHERE B.k_akun = A.k_akun AND 
B.k_kel=A.k_kel AND B.k_jenis = A.k_jenis AND B.k_obyek=A.k_obyek AND 
B.k_rekening=A.k_rekening and A.kd_skpd='SD001' AND C.k_akun = B.k_akun AND 
C.k_kel=B.k_kel AND C.k_jenis = B.k_jenis AND C.k_obyek = B.k_obyek AND 
C.k_rekening = B.k_rekening and C.kd_skpd='SD001' AND C.tahun_target = 
'2017'
) T2
ON T1.kd_skpd = T2.kd_skpd
AND T1.no_rekening = T2.no_rekening
AND T1.nama = T2.nama
)
) AS T
```

and this is the error message

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'UNION
SELECT '' as kd,CONCAT_WS(' ',B.k_akun,B.k_kel,'','','') as no_rekening, ' 
at line 6
```

I have ran similar query using that in postgresql and it's working, but it doesn't work in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parentheses that don't belong:

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.target FROM ((SELECT
```

should be

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.target FROM (SELECT
```

and

```
)) AS T
```

should be

```
) AS T
```

Then the query contains invalid aggregations, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
  '' as kd,
  CONCAT_WS(' ',B.k_akun,'','','','') as no_rekening, 
  B.nm_akun, 
  SUM(A.nominal_target) as target 
from m_akun_rek B, target_tahunan A
WHERE A.kd_skpd ='SD001' AND A.k_akun = B.k_akun AND A.tahun_target = '2017'
```

Here you want a single result row, for you are using `SUM` without any `GROUP BY`. But `CONCAT_WS(...)` and `B.nm_akun` are no aggregates. So which row's values are you actually trying to access here? This is invalid SQL. Early MySQL versions didn't raise an error on that, but they should have.

(Apart from that this is a horrible query. The comma-separated joins indicate that parts of the query were probably written in the 1980s. And then those many UNIONs give the DBMS quite a lot of work to do with looking for duplicates. Maybe you can replace some of the `UNION` to `UNION ALL` where duplicates cannot occur.)

Comment: Great job !, your answer fix my problem, thankyou so much bruh.

Answer (score 0):

error lies here

```
    SELECT '' as kd,CONCAT_WS('',
B.k_akun,B.k_kel,B.k_jenis,B.k_obyek,B.k_rekening) as no_rekening, 
        B.nm_rekening from m_rekening B, rekening_skpd A WHERE B.k_akun = A.k_akun 
        AND B.k_kel=A.k_kel AND B.k_jenis = A.k_jenis AND B.k_obyek=A.k_obyek AND 
        B.k_rekening=A.k_rekening and A.kd_skpd='SD001'
        ) T1
        LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT skpd.kd_skpd AS kd_skpd,CONCAT_WS(' ','','','','','') as 
        no_rekening, skpd.nm_skpd as nama,'' as target from skpd WHERE 
        skpd.kd_skpd='SD001'
        UNION
```

you didnt close the left join select query and didnt put the condition for joining

do like this

```
select T1.kd,t1.no_rekening,T1.nm_rekening from
    (SELECT '' as kd,CONCAT_WS('',
        B.k_akun,B.k_kel,B.k_jenis,B.k_obyek,B.k_rekening) as no_rekening, 
                B.nm_rekening from m_rekening B, rekening_skpd A WHERE B.k_akun = A.k_akun 
                AND B.k_kel=A.k_kel AND B.k_jenis = A.k_jenis AND B.k_obyek=A.k_obyek AND 
                B.k_rekening=A.k_rekening and A.kd_skpd='SD001'
                ) T1
                LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT skpd.kd_skpd AS kd_skpd,CONCAT_WS(' ','','','','','') as 
                no_rekening, skpd.nm_skpd as nama,'' as target from skpd) T2 
    on T1....... = T2....... WHERE 
                skpd.kd_skpd='SD001'
                UNION
```

Comment: thankyou so much for your answer but it still doesnt work